# How to retrieve/filter data from a multilevel dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im fairly new to pandas (and Python) and Im having some trouble working with a multilevel dataframe, specifically trying to apply some filtering to the dataframe.

To put this on context, Im using the requests library to fetch data from a web, then creating the dataframe:

```
req = requests.get('url')
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(req.json()['results'])
```

This leads to:

```
  id                            data  score
0  1  {'rank': 1, 'active': 'true'}     178
1  2  {'rank': 3, 'active': 'false'}    125
```

Now, I need to filter this using the score (score > 150) and the active value from the data column (active == 'true'). I can easily do the first part with:

```
df.query('score > ' '150')
```

But Im not able to filter by 'active' too. I have tried to retrieve the active values from the data column aside, but nothing. I've read some of the official pandas documentation, a lot of similar questions, tried its solutions, but no luck so far :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['data'].tolist()))
df[(df['score'] > 150) & (df['active'])]
```

Comment: Thanks Vivek, it works and most important, I can understand the solution. Time to keep learning pandas.

Comment: you are welcome :)